# REST convention for function based services

Tags: rest, uri, naming-conventions

The typical REST endpoints service looks like this for an entity.

```
GET /products (list)
GET /products/:id (detail of a specific product)
POST /products (insert)
PUT /products/:id (update)
DELETE /products/:id (delete)
```

but if I've a requirement to return some custom result, for example

```
SELECT MAX(lastModified) FROM product
```

How would you form a REST request (method + URL) based on above or similar custom results?

Comment: You can make a `products/stats` endpoint which will be returning additional data about the products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only interested in the "lastModifed" product  from your list of products (i.e. the product with MAX(lastModified)) then:

```
GET /products/lastModified
```

Comment: `MAX(lastModified)` is a function in SQL applied to all rows of the table, not a specific row with an :id, therefore, :id is not available/applicable. What @Opal suggested is in conflict with my existing router (edited) `GET /products/:id`

Comment: Thanks but I guess the router (node.js, expressjs) will have a problem distinguishing between two similar requests. 1) `GET /products/:id` 2) `GET /products/lastModified`. For router both will be the same routes and same function calls

Comment: In expressjs you can set-up route paths along with regular expressions, so you can route traffic to the correct method. See the "Route Paths" section [here](http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html). Hence you could have "app.get('/lastModified',...", to target the lastModified controller method.